# Distinct results from mysql database as a drop down list / php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sure i posted this last night, but I can't find it, and my account says I've asked 0 questions. anyway...

I have a field in my MySQL Database that contains UK Counties. I'd like to list these in a drop down box so they may be selected by a user, to select the area of the UK they'd like to see results from.

I have this so far... but my drop down box appears empty?

any help greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

//set variable
$option = '';

// Get the county names from database - no duplicates
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT tradingCounty FROM offers";

// execute the query, $result will hold all of the Counties in an array
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $option .="<option>" . $row['tradingCounty'] . "</option>";
    echo $option;
}

echo "<form id='filter' name='filter' method='post' action='resultssimple.php'>
        <p><label>County</label></p>
        <select name='filter' id='filter'>" . $option . "</select>
        </form>";
?>
```

Comment: You are mixing `mysqli` and `mysql` functions.

Comment: also looks like youre `echo $option;` is before the required HTML `<select>` element. which could be causing issues

Comment: I've just replaced '$row = mysql_fetch_array' with  '$row = mysqli_fetch_array' and it seems to work now...

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $option .="<option value='". $row['tradingCounty'] .  '">" . $row['tradingCounty'] . "</option>"; 
}
```

You don't echo the option in the while loop, and need the option value attribute.

Comment: Tried to answer on mobile and hard to tell if the code snippet is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it

```
    echo "<form id='filter' name='filter' method='post' action='resultssimple.php'>
            <p><label>County</label></p>
            <select name='filter' id='filter'>";
                // Get the county names from database - no duplicates
                $query = "SELECT DISTINCT tradingCounty FROM offers";

        // execute the query, $result will hold all of the Counties in an array
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $option .="<option>" . $row['tradingCounty'] . "</option>";
            echo $option;
        }

    echo "</select>
    </form>";
```

Answer (score 0):

`$result = $mysqli->query($query);
    while($row = $result->fetch_array())
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }`

Use the above code syntax for mysqli.